# Телеграмм бот напоминалка, проблема остановки

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Я писал телеграм бот который каждые 30мин или час отправляет пользователю напоминание, но при нажатии на кнопку Остановить, у всех пользователей останавливается, как можно это исправить?

```
i = True
def loop_b():
global i
    if message.text == 'Напомни через 30 минут':
        i = True
        while i:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(3)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, random_rus_30m(), reply_markup=start_stop_button_rus())
    if message.text == 'Напомни через 1 час':
        i = True
        while i:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(6)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, random_rus_1h(), reply_markup=start_stop_button_rus())

    if message.text == 'Remind after 30 minutes':
        i = True
        while i:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(3)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, random_eng_30m(), reply_markup=start_stop_button_eng())
    if message.text == 'Remind after 1 hour':
        i = True
        while i:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(6)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, random_eng_1h(), reply_markup=start_stop_button_eng())

    if message.text == 'Остановить':
        i = False
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Остановили', reply_markup=start_stop_button_eng())
        print(i)
    if message.text == 'Stop':
        i = False
        print(i)



if __name__ == '__main__':
Thread(target=loop_a).start()
```

Comment: Удивительно, что это работает на отправку уведомлений :) Я бы сделал так: **1)** Сделать таблицу в базе (можно из коробки использовать sqlite3) **2)** Добавлять в нее `chat_id`, время/дата отправки, флаг (отправили или нет) **3)** Бот будет добавлять или удалять из таблицы (можно завести еще столбец -- `enabled` и по нему определять включено или отключено напоминание или непариться и удалять записи по `chat_id`) **4)** Отдельный поток проверяет таблицу каждые n-секунд и проверяет настало ли время отправки

Comment: @gil9red А без БД никак? Я новичок, даже не представляю как с базой связывать, а чтоб читать недостаточно времени, завтра должен сдавать уже. Например можно ли сделать так чтобы он по chat_id считывал тех, которые нажали кнопку Остановить и только им останавливать?

Comment: Можно, вместо базы храните те данные, например, в списке, просто если бот завершится (банально упадет с ошибкой), то все напоминания будут им забыты. А так, все что я описал выше можно попробовать сделать, заменив таблицу базы на список